# Facebook's FriendPickerFragment on Android seems very slow

Tags: android, facebook

Has anyone else encountered problems with the performance of the FriendPickerFragment from Facebook? I'm following the tutorial for showing friends ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/show-friends/ ), but it takes minutes to scroll down a list of less than 300 friends.

Since no one else has posted this concern, I'm inclined to think I'm doing something wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get it to perform as well as the "native" friend list in Facebook's Android app?

Your guidance is greatly appreciated!
-Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use [Universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

This is for listView optimization and improving performance if your listView contain images from web.

**Features:**

- Multithread image loading Possibility of wide tuning ImageLoader's
- configuration (thread executors, downlaoder, decoder, memory and disc
- cache, display image options, and others) Possibility of image
- caching in memory and/or on device's file sysytem (or SD card)
- Possibility to "listen" loading process Possibility to customize
   every display image call with separated options Widget support

Comment: Haris, my apologies for not getting back to you quicker - I only recently noticed that this question had a response.